# переключение классов в массиве по таймеру

Tags: javascript, jquery, функции, циклы

есть массив элементов с одинаковыми классами, нужно, чтоб каждую секунду добавлялся/удалялся класс элементам массива по очереди. как правильно описать такую функцию?

на данный момент запнулся на моменте:

```
var i = 0;

setInterval(function(){

    var toHover = $('.st-b > a');

    var objs = toHover.map(function(){
        return this;
    }).get();

    var art = objs[i++];

    // art.toggleClass('hover');
    console.log(art);
    console.log('hover+');

    setTimeout(function(){

        // art.toggleClass('hover');
        console.log(art);
        console.log('hover-');

    },1000);

    if(i >= objs.length) i = 0;

},3000);
```

если раскомментировать - выводится ошибка

Comment: странно почему сейчас ошибка не выводится, учитывая, что идет попытка обращения к полю переменной, которая еще не инициализирована `var art = objs[i++];`

Comment: видимо, криво скопипастил.
    `var art = objs[i++];`
после 
    `var objs = toHover.map(function(){
        return this;
    }).get();`
идёт, естественно

Comment: Вы обращаетесь к переменной до ее инициализации

Comment: проблема в том, что в этот момент `objs` еще _undefined_, поэтому при попытке сделать `objs[i++]` будет исключение

Comment: @Grundy поправил место объявления `art`

Comment: И какая ошибка теперь?

Comment: @Grundy
если раскомментировать `art.toggleClass('hover');` то ошибка
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleClass' of undefined`

Comment: Попробуй `$(art).toggleClass('hover');`. У тебя art не JQuery элемент

Comment: @Yuri спасибо! теперь работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что ты пытаешься вызвать метод jQuery [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) у нативного html элемента. У него такого метода нет, поэтому бросается исключение.

Для исправления, нужно либо использовать средства нативного DOM, [`classList.toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) либо работать с jQuery объектами.

Например:

```
var art = toHover.eq(i);
art.toggleClass(...);
```

не забыв при этом вынести инициализацию `toHover` из интервала, если количество элементов не будет меняться в процессе работы программы.

---

Но основная проблема в том, что похоже у тебя *нет* вообще элементов соответствующих селектору, поэтому `art` -> *undefined* и при попытке вызвать у него функцию бросается исключение.

Стоит проверить разметку, селектор, время когда вызывается функция.

Comment: благодарю за разъяснение, помогла банальная обёртка
$(art)

Comment: @wannaBpro, На самом деле не помогла. `art` у тебя все еще _undefined_ и никто не знает почему, просто jQuery на пустой коллекции не выполняет вызванный метод, и ты просто скрыл ошибку.

Comment: @wannaBpro, также обрати внимание - я убрал ненужный `objs`. А `map(function(){
        return this;
    })` бесполезна для jQuery и если этот вызов убрать - ничего не поменяется

Comment: всё работает! огромное спасибо!